# Can anyone please explain me how this "if (blnRtrn == true)" works?

Tags: javascript

i am building a form that has to validate every field.irrespective of whether previous filled or not...(ie simultaneous validation of the individual field).i found hw to do it but cannot understand the code!!!!(if (blnRtrn == true)   part). if any one can explain plz

`

```
  var blnRtrn=true;
  var name=document.getElementById('uname').value;
  var pass=document.getElementById('password').value;
  var cpass=document.getElementById('confirmpassword').value;

  if(name.length==0){
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="Enter UseName";
    blnRtrn = false;        
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="";
}   
   if(pass.length==0){
    document.getElementById('msg1').innerHTML="Enter password";
    blnRtrn = false;        
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('msg1').innerHTML="";
}   

   if(cpass.length==0){
    document.getElementById('msg2').innerHTML="Enter confirm password";
    blnRtrn = false;        
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('msg2').innerHTML="";
}   

  if (blnRtrn == true)
    {
document.forms[0].actionValue.value = '1';
     document.forms[0].submit();
    }
   </script>`
```

Comment: If the value of blnRtrn is true the script is setting the value of actionValue field as 1 and submit the form

Comment: ok..i tried the same thing without using the blnRtrn i.e i wrote "return false" in place of "blnRtrn=false" and in submit button i wrote <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return the_function_name_of_javascript()".but both output are not same.y is tht?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logic explained**

Assume everything is ok:

```
var blnRtrn=true;
```

Check various possible errors

```
if(name.length==0)
```

If there is an error, show a message

```
document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="Enter UseName";
```

... and change the variable that says everything is ok:

```
blnRtrn = false;
```

Finally, after the every potential error has been checked, see if the first assumption holds (if any of the checks failed or not):

```
if (blnRtrn == true)
```

If everything is ok, submit the form:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added inline comments to explain what it does.

```
// blnRtrn is the variable determines whether the form is to be submitted or not. 
// It is set to true by default and is set to false if any of the validation given above this code fails.
if (blnRtrn == true) { // if it is true (i.e) all validation checks are passed
    document.forms[0].actionValue.value = '1'; // Set the value of actionValue field to 1
    document.forms[0].submit(); // Submit the form
}
```

Comment: thank u...i tried the same prog without using the blnRtrn i.e i wrote "return false" in place of "blnRtrn=false" and in submit button i wrote <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return the_function_name_of_javascript()".but both output are not same.y is tht?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a loop !
This validation is very simple, and work as it :

1. We define a variable (`blnRtrn`) which will represent our validation. We assume it is true from the beggining.
2. The different tests such as 
   `if(name.length == 0) {
       document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="Enter UseName";
       blnRtrn = false;

   }`
   will *try* to change the variable to false in order to unvalidate the form.
3. In the end, if `blnRtrn` is still true, so all tests passed, the form is validated and can be sent.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no loop in the Source you posted. Loops are "for" and "while" and so on. "if" is not a loop, as it is used only once.

now to your problem. The following will happen once the user klicks submit:

1. blnRtrn is set to true.
2. If the length of the text entered into the "name" field is zero (==there is no text entered), blnRtrn is set to false, and a Message is output to the user.
3. If the length of the text entered into the "pass" field is zero (==there is no text entered), blnRtrn is set to false, and a Message is output to the user.
4. If the length of the text entered into the "cpass" field is zero (==there is no text entered), blnRtrn is set to false, and a Message is output to the user.
5. Now your program tests if blnRtrn is still true. If it is, all fields were correctly filled out and the form is submitted. if blnRtrn is not true anymore, the user must have forgotten to input something into one of the fields, and the form submission is cancelled.

Comment: thank u for correctng me...i tried the same prog without using the blnRtrn i.e i wrote "return false" in place of "blnRtrn=false" and in submit button i wrote <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return the_function_name_of_javascript()".but both output are not same.y is tht?